# C++ while loop not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string option;
    cout << "Would like water, beer, or rum?--> ";
    cin >> option;
    while( option != "water" || option != "beer" || option != "rum" )
        {
        cout << "You did not choose a valid option. Try again.\n";
        cout << "Would you like water, beer, or rum?-->";
        cin >> option;
        }
}
```

Why doesn't this code ever exit the loop even though the user enters the right option?

Answer (score 11):

Read your condition out loud - "run the loop while `option` is not `"water"` **or** `option` is not `"beer"` **or**...".

When should it stop?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong logical operator. You want **all** of your conditions to be true (`option` not equal to water, not equal to beer, and not equal to rum), so you should be using **and** (`&&`). **Or** (`||`) means that the expression is true if **any** of the conditions are true, and since the values are mutually exclusive, that will always be the case, hence your infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your `||`s should be `&&`s because a `option` can only have one value.

```
while (option != "water" && option != "beer" && option != "rum")
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement is always true:

```
option != "water" || option != "beer" || option != "rum"
```

If `option` is "water," then it's not "beer," so the statement is true.  If `option` is "beer," it's not "water," so the statement is true (assuming you have a good beer, of course.)

I think you meant to write

```
option != "water" && option != "beer" && option != "rum"
```

That way, as soon as `option` takes on any of these values, the loop will exit.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Almost always `!= ||` sequences are wrong and && should be used. If one comparison fails the others are true, hence the entire condition is always true. If you are not unequal to one you are certainly unequal to others.

With experience you'll itch seeing such a construct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container to store the valid options and check to see whether the selection is in the container:

```
set<string> validOptions = { "water", "beer", "rum"};

while(validOptions.count(option) == 0) {
    // .. etc
}
```