# How do I get multiple conditions within one while loop?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, comparison

I am using a while loop and I want to user to input r, R, p, or P. But when I add more than one condition like:

```
while ((userInput != "r") || (userInput != "p" || (userInput != "R") || (userInput!= "P")) {
    cout << "Please enter a valid option" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
}
```

my program will forever be stuck in the loop. Where as if I input it like this:

```
while (userInput != "r") {
    cout << "Please enter a valid option" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
}
```

Then my code will exit the for loop if user inputs "r"
So why does the first block of code not work? I have no errors, which means it has to be a logical error but I do not understand. How can I get more thano ne condition in a for loop and make it work?

Comment: `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but you don’t need all those parentheses.  `if ((a != “Y”) || (a != “p”))` can be written as `if (a != “Y” || a != “p”)`. Read about operator precedence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ while loop not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221201/c-while-loop-not-working)

Comment: [How do I get multiple conditions within one while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47402665/995714), [I don't exactly understand why my while loop is not catching any of these conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70851009/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||` because using `||` the condition in the `while` is always `true`. When you write  “r”, for example, the condition `userinput != r` is false but the rest are true, with `&&` all the expressions turn to `false` and the `while` ends.

Answer (score 2):

`Why does the above condition not work?`

The reason is because if you say `x is not 3 or x is not 5`, then if `x` is `3`, then `x` is not `5`, so the entire statement evaluates to true. Your different `userInput != 'r'` and `userInput != 'p'` are just like that situation with the `x`.

To show it simpler, I'll show a truth table for `or`. When the expression evaluates to true, your while loop would continue below those circumstances, where `p` and `q` are statements that may be true or false like `userInput != 'r'`.

```
||  -- or
 q\p|_T_|_F_|
 _T_|_T_|_T_|
 _F_|_T_|_F_|
```

Meaning that with an `or` clause, the only way it's false is if all parts are false.

An `And` clause appears to be what you want. It's truth table is:

```
&&  -- and
 q\p|_T_|_F_|
 _T_|_T_|_F_|
 _F_|_F_|_F_|
```

Meaning, that with an `and` clause, the only way for it to be true is if all clauses are true.

So if you want the response to be neither r nor p nor R nor P, etc, use `&&` for and:

```
while ((userInput != "r") && (userInput != "p") && (userInput != "R") && (userInput!= "P")) {
```

And then the while loop will exit as soon as `userInput` does not match any of `r`, `p`, `R` or `P`. This is because as the program evaluates, it checks:

With the example of userInput as "g":

Does the userInput `g` equal `r`? No. So the first clause is True. Does the userInput `g` equal `p`? No. So the second clause is True. Does the userInput `g` equal `R`? No. So the third clause is True. Does the userInput `g` equal `P`? No. So the fourth clause is True. Since all four are true, then the whole statement is true, and the while loop continues.

With the example of userInput as "R":

Does the userInput `g` equal `R`? No. So the first clause is True. Does the userInput `g` equal `R`? No. So the second clause is True. Does the userInput `g` equal `R`? YES. So the third clause is False. Since a part of the statement is false, the whole and clause is false, so the while loop exits.